# Adding static files to spring MVC project in netbeans

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have tried to research on this topic and the answers and solutions that I am getting are not helping
I am new to spring mvc I am trying to add my own static files to it but I keep getting the error of file not found

Here is my project structure

[image: Project structure]

I have also added these lines of code to dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I have then tried to add a favicon to my jsp file as such

```
    <head>
     ...
     <!--Begin Spring variables-->
     <spring:url value="/resources/images/favicon.ico" var="favicon" />
     <spring:url value="/resources/css/style.css" var="style" />
     <spring:url value="/resources/js/functions.js" var="functions" />
     <!--End spring variables-->

     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${favicon}" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="${style}" />
     ...
    </head>
```

Adding js and css files in the same way but I still get errors.

What could I be doing wrong?

If none why is it not working

My spring version is 4.0.1
I would also appreciate any tutorials that would help me solve this and move on with my projects

**Note** Adding this line

```
     <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to the dispatcher file causes glassfish to fail launching the project but removing it loads the project but without the resources
I have noted that the server fails to deploy the project when I include any of the lines :

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

here is the server's error logs

[Server logs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dhjg30zpr2g8h8/server%20logs.txt?dl=0)

I have also noted that I can add images and other files but I can not add images to my containers using css 
I.e I can not do this

```
    <div style="background-image: url('${banner}');
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         background-size: cover;">
```

meaning that the added static files don't work correctly

this is the entire dispatcher file

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
    <!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Comment: If i was to make a guess, i'd say your deployment descriptor is not actually deploying the resources directory.  Do you know how to see what the actual deployed structure looks like? Is it truly /web-inf/resources/... ?

Comment: I don't think I know how to get to see that. Would you mind showing me

Comment: I don't use netbeans. But I've also not used spring:url and just tried it, and it left off the 'resources' part of the path.  have you ensured the rendered url is what you expect?  run your app and view the source rendered to the browser to confirm.

Comment: I have and the path rendered is correct but the resource is not loaded. have you read the updated question?

Comment: can you show the xml namespaces code of dispatcher-servlet.xml ?